# how to show multiple models (3 layer structure) in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a data structure with three tables(DAL classes) as below:

```
public class Subject
 {
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SubjectContact> SubjectContacts{ get; set; }
 }

 public class SubjectContact
 {
    [Key]
    public int SubjectContactId { get; set; }
    public int InfoTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual InfoType IntoType{ get; set; }
    public string InTypeValue { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject{ get; set; }
 }

 public class InfoType
 {
    [Key]
    public int InfoTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int SubjectContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SubjectContact> SubjectContacts{ get; set; }
 }
```

Subject:
SubjectId Name Company Address
101 John C1 A1
102 Michael C2 A2
103 Elizabeth C3 A3

SubjectContact:
SubjectContactId InfoTypeId InfoTypeValue SubjectId
1001 1000001 16174350000 101
1002 1000002 16177891234 101
1003 1000003 john@gmail.com 101
1004 1000001 13027546200 102
1005 1000004 lizAndHeather 102

InfoType
InfoTypeId TypeName
1000001 Cell Phone
1000002 Home Phone
1000003 Email
1000004 Skype

The final View will be something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<FootViewModel>

<ul>
@foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <li>
        @i.Subjects
    </li>

    @foreach (var j in Model.Subjects)
    {
        <li>
        @j.SubjectContacts 
        @Model.InfoType.TypeName
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

The FootViewModel should be something as below:

```
public class FootViewModel
{
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> SubjectContactInfos { get; set; }
    public List<InfoType> InfoTypes { get; set; }
}
```

But this is a wrong one because it is lack a relationship between SubjectContacts and InfoTypes. Could you give me some idea how to construct the viewmodel FootViewModel? Thanks!

Comment: Use Display or Editor Templates (depending if you need to view or edit your model).

Comment: Can `Subject` contain only one `SubjectContact` or a collection of `SubjectContact`? Your `Subject` data model should contain (for example) public virtual ICollection<SubjectContact> Contacts { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks for your correction. A subject contains a list of subjectContacts. I think I gave a wrong description. The structure should be like this:

Subject:   
SubjectId Name Company Address
101 John C1 A1
102 Michael C2 A2
103 Elizabeth C3 A3
   
SubjectContact: 
SubjectContactId InfoTypeId InfoTypeValue SubjectId
1001 1000001 16174350000 101
1002 1000002 16177891234 101
1003 1000003 john@gmail.com 101
1004 1000001 13027546200 102
1005 1000004 liz@hotmail.com 102
   
InfoType:
InfoTypeId TypeName  
1000001 Cell Phone  
1000002 Home Phone  
1000003 Email  
1000004 Skype

Comment: That's impossible to read in comments. Assuming your using EF, then if  a `Subject` contains a collection of `SubjectContact` then add `public virtual ICollection<SubjectContact> SubjectContacts { get; set; }` to your `Subject` model (and `SubjectContact` will contain similar property for `InfoType`) Refer [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) to understand how to set up your navigational properties.

Comment: Thank you. I am really quite new to mvc and entity framework.

Comment: Then in your controller method, using `IEnumerable<Subject> model = db.Subjects;` will populate your data model correctly, and if you returned that to the view with `@model IEnumerable<Subject>` you can just use `@foreach(var subject in Model) { .... foreach(var contact in subject.SubjectContacts) { .... foreach(var info in contact.InfoTypes){ ...`. If you want to use view models (which you should), then it needs to follow the same structure

Comment: `SubjectVM` will contain a property `IEnumerable<SubjectContactVM>` and `SubjectContactVM` will contain a property `IEnumerable<InfoTypeVM>`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This makes the solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Stephen's correction. A subject contains a list of subjectContacts. I think I gave a wrong description. In fact the structure should be like this:

Subject:
SubjectId   Name    Company Address
101 John    C1  A1
102 Michael C2  A2
103 Elizabeth   C3  A3

SubjectContact:
SubjectContactId    InfoTypeId  InfoTypeValue   SubjectId
1001    1000001 16174350000 101
1002    1000002 16177891234 101
1003    1000003 john@gmail.com  101
1004    1000001 13027546200 102
1005    1000004 lizAndHeather   102

InfoType
InfoTypeId  TypeName
1000001 Cell Phone
1000002 Home Phone
1000003 Email
1000004 Skype

I made a mid ViewModel ContactValueViewModel as below, so hope this will work:

```
public class FootViewModel
{
    public SubjectViewModel Subject { get; set; }
    public List<ContactValueViewModel> ContactValues{ get; set; }
}

public class ContactValueViewModel
{
    public SubjectContactInfoViewModel SubjectContactInfo { get; set; }
    public InfoTypeViewModel InfoTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This section is for answers. Please delete and edit your question with the additional information.